# Is it possible to invite a collaborator when publishing photos using the Instagram Graph API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

In October 2021 Instagram launched a new feature called Collabs which allows people to co-author Feed Posts and Reels. When posting (only in the app) you can 'Invite a collaborator'. This uses a similar interface to tag users, feels like it's related.

https://www.instagram.com/p/CVOKMVNARZX/

We have a working implementation of Content Publishing using the Instagram Graph API. When posting media you can tag other users by using user_tags.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing#publish-with-tagged-users

```
POST graph.facebook.com/17841400008460056/media? 
image_url=https//www.example.com/images/bronzed-fonzes.jpg
&caption=#BronzedFonzes!
&user_tags=
[
  {
    username:'kevinhart4real',
    x: 0.5,
    y: 0.8
  },
  {
    username:'therock',
    x: 0.3,
    y: 0.2
  }
]
```

We'd like to use the API to tag a collaborator to the published media. It doesn't seem to be in the Meta documentation, but is this possible? Again, feels like its related to the user_tags variable.

Comment: Would be interesting to know more information about this matter. I'm interested too

Comment: @alexmcfarlane Did you get the answer to this question ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collaborators seems to be available now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media

You have to add a list of usernames to the Post request like this:

```
POST graph.facebook.com/17841400008460056/media
  ?image_url=https//www.example.com/images/bronzed-fonzes.jpg
  &caption=#BronzedFonzes!
  &collaborators= [‘username1’,’username2’]
```